# Preloading Mesh Data in Three.js

Tags: three.js

It appears that THREE.js sends mesh (geometry and material) information to the card only when an object is first rendered. Unfortunately this can cause noticeable hiccups in frame rate when a new object comes on the scene.

Is there a way to utilize the three.js framework (or is there a parameter I'm missing) to send the mesh data down to the card immediately after the associated resources are loaded, rather than on first render? I've considered creating a temporary / off-screen scene that I could put each object into on load, render once, and the discard. I've also tried calling the low-level renderer functions directly with mock data to force the write. It works, but both are hacks.

Any suggestions?

Three.js r67.

Comment: How is rendering off screen a hack?

Comment: @ClassicThunder, maybe it is semantics, but imo, being forced to perform something to get around a limitation of the software you are using is a hack. Having the control to explicitly send data to the card is a very basic and reasonable requirement of any graphics engine. It is an unnecessary burden on the developer to manage, render, and then dispose of resources **just** to get the data to the card. But you might not feel the same way.